# `marked_for_destruction?' for false:FalseClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still learning Rails and in my app I'm trying to implement notifications sended to admin when user creates holiday leave request. I'm trying to follow up two, pretty much the same, solutions - [Easy Notification System](http://aalvarez.me/blog/posts/easy-notification-system-in-rails.html) which is inspired of [Chris Olivier's navbar Notifications](https://gorails.com/episodes/in-app-navbar-notifications) and I'm stuck at the beginning. When user is trying to create holiday leave request I recive an error:

**undefined method `marked_for_destruction?' for false:FalseClass**

I tried defining this method in controller, however, it didn't work.

leave.rb model:

```
class Leave < ApplicationRecord

after_create :create_notifications
belongs_to :user, optional: true

private

def recipients
[user.admin]
end

def create_notifications
recipients.each do |recipient|
  Notification.create(recipient: recipient, actor: self.user,
    action: 'posted', notifiable: self)
end
end
```

user.rb model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

has_many :notifications, foreign_key: :recipient_id
has_many :leaves, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Leaves controller:

```
def create
@leave = Leave.new(leave_params)
@user = User.new


if @leave.save
  redirect_to leaves_path
else
  render :new
end
end
```

I thought that I have to add `'autosave: true'` to the `has_many` ,

and it should looks like
`has_many :leaves, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true`

but it didn't work either.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Where is the code that actually tries to call `marked_for_destruction?`? It looks like you're calling it on a value of `false` instead of the desired object.

Comment: Right know, as you see, I don't have `marked_for_destruction` at all. What is the purpose of this method?

Comment: Alright, if it's not called from any of your code, then we'll need a full stacktrace to get to the bottom of this so we can see where it's coming from.

Comment: You mean something like this [link](https://i.imgur.com/Xwj02Tq.png) ?

Comment: Yes, although to see the full picture, you'll need to click on "Full Trace" so that we can see everything.

Comment: Quite a lot of this, I hope it will be useful - [first](https://imgur.com/2hSAwMT) [second](https://imgur.com/vGdm7oq) [third](https://imgur.com/3DctSVo) [last one](https://imgur.com/kRHPXWY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your notification system, you try to send a notif to admins every time a `Leave` is created.

Assuming that, your error comes from your `recipients` method:
`[user.admin]` returns `[true]` or `[false]`
and when you iterate on it, you do: `Notification.create(recipient: true/false, ...)`

You can fix your system by creating a user scope for admins:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  #...
  scope :admins, -> { where(admin: true) }
end
```

and change the `recipients` method like:

```
class Leave < ApplicationRecord
  #...
  private

  def recipients
    User.admins
  end

  def create_notifications
    #...
  end
end
```

Comment: Great! I didn't have any errors however notification wasn't created, when I jumped to the rails console and make `Notification.all` I got empty array instead.

Comment: @wichru maybe because you don't have any users admins (`admin: true`) ?

Comment: Hehe nope, the reason was even more stupid - I forgot uncomment `after_create :create_notifications` action. Now it works perfectly fine!. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you [look at the code of the presence validator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/presence.rb#L8), you'll see that it traverses an `Enumerable` and calls `marked_for_destruction?` on its elements.

Looking at your code, this is an indication that one of the values you're trying to assign to your associations is `false` instead of the ActiveRecord object you're expecting.

To debug the issue, I recommend checking out [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/) and the `pry-byebug` gem: with it you can add a breakpoint (`binding.pry`) into the line before `Notification.create` and check out the values of `recipient` and `self.user`.